# Constraints have me fumbling

Tags: ios, constraints

Tried a lot of combinations with the x,y,width and height using auto layout but have had no luck. For frame of reference check out this image of iPhone 7s on storyboard

*Remember the OFF in relation to the fries in the background

[image: iPhone 7s]

Then check out this

[image: iPhone 5]

I'm very confused on what to do.

Comment: try setting top constraint <=

Comment: What you need to achieve?

Comment: I would just like to keep everything in proportion, the background image scales but the buttons Y is abysmal

Comment: If you need proportion you need add an helper view that resizes proportionally and then pin your button to that view

Comment: That is primarily due to difference in size of canvas on your storyboard compared to that used when running the app. Noticed you used iPhone7 for storyboard and iPhone5 for testing. If your app is also required to display correctly on older devices you have to put more thought to constraints above x,y,width.height.

Comment: @TusharSharma no success, ill reset and try once more

Comment: @MohamedSalad you need your OFF button separated proportionally from bottom and right sides?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yeah, the right side is correct but wether I try to constrain from Y top and Y bottom it's either out of view or wrong place.

Comment: If you want it proportionate, consider using the horizontal/vertical align to container and set it's multiplier to the that portion of the screen you want it.

Comment: @BenOng can you post an example of that? I use another way to do this

Comment: @ReinierMelian I am typing an answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want a View to be in a certain portion of its superview, you can use align constraint with multiplier. First apply these constraints you your view:

[image]

Then modify each of the multiplier to the portion you want it to be, from the center to the edge is between value 1 to 2:

[image]
[image]

Note the values I used(1.7 & 1.9) brings the center of the view to 70% and 90% point between the center and edge of the superview. Having the multiplier at 2 will guarantee half your view be outside your superview.

Reminder too that these two constraints only determines the X and Y position of your view. You will need to add more to determine its width and height which I did beforehand.